# Why does the camel to route fail

Tags: apache-camel

I have a very simple piece of camel code.

```
public class MainApp2 {

    /**
     * A main() so we can easily run these routing rules in our IDE
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("sftp://ghana.corp.sensis.com:22/orders/?username=dsargrad&password=xxx")
                        .log("Received order: ${header.CamelFileName}")
                        //.to("file:///home/dsargrad/order_processed")
                        .to("file:data/outbox")
                        ;
            }
        });

        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000000);

        context.stop();

    }

}
```

The "from" portion of the route works ok. I am able to connect to the FTP server and find files in the "orders" directory. The log message indicates that.

The content of the orders folder is a single file:
[image]

However when I then try  to copy those files to a folder, using the to portion of the route, I see the following failure

[image]

I've tried this both with a relative path and an absolute path (/home/dsargrad/order_processed). I've verified the existence of both paths. The relative path is defined relative to the location that I run the java application.

The following is the valid absolute path.
[image]

The following is the failure with the absolute path.

[image]

The following picture shows the content of the orders folder from an independent FTP client. This tells me that the FTP service and the username/password is fine.

[image]

Comment: What is really odd is that if I replace the from(sftp) with a from(file:) and use identically the same to(file), then the route works just fine.

Comment: Please help me to understand the following portion of the call stack "No type converter available to convert from ... RemoteFile to .... InputStream"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common error when running "uber" jar with dependencies. Some Maven plugins (e.g. `maven-assembly-plugin`) excludes some `META-INF` entries, which are required for correct function of type conversion. See this FAQ entry: [How to create executable JAR for camel-main project](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-create-executable-jar-camel-main.html).

I suggest to use `maven-shade-plugin` with following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>executable-jar</shadedClassifierName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>my.package.MainClass</mainClass> <!-- Change main class here -->
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverterLoader</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Bedla, Thanks for this feedback. I will read through the link you suggested, and I will also try the maven plugin you suggest. So glad to get feedback from the community.

Comment: I only created an "uber" jar because I figured that was the easiest way to go. Clearly I created problems in the process. What is the proper way to run a non-uber jar containing a camel application?

Comment: Yeah see this FAQ too: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-use-a-big-uber-jar.html

Comment: Thanks  @ClausIbsen